# Does SharedPreferences.Editor commit() only write back changes made, or the entire set of preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

When you call commit on a SharedPreferences.Editor, does it only write back the values that
were changed, or does it write back all the values in the SharedPreference object its linked too, whether they were changed or not?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29):

> Commit your preferences **changes** back from this Editor to the SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs the requested **modifications**, replacing whatever is currently in the SharedPreferences.

It appears to suggest that the data is only modified, not overwritten if it is the same. Keep in mind though, that multiple calls to `commit()` will yield only one change (the final one).

Comment: Yeah I saw that too and was hoping thats what it meant, but I want to see if anyone knows for sure / through experience whether it clobbers unchanged values in SharedPreferences..

Comment: Having a look at the source code for SharedPreferencesImpl (https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/jellybean/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java), the Editor maintains a HashMap of modifications and only applies those modifications. No clobbering of unmodified values.

Comment: @nEx.Software Great resource and link!

Comment: @nEx.Software awesome thats exactly what I was looking for.